# How can i resize image in moviepy so that it perfectly fits in 1980x1080?

Tags: python, math, size, moviepy

So I'm trying to resize an image and maintain its ratio so that it perfectly fits in 1980x1080 in the moviepy library.

Currently, I'm doing this with a function like this:

```
def FitClip(size):
    
    #size is basicly clip.size
    clipRes = size
    #print(size)

    v = ''
    
    if clipRes[0] >= clipRes[1]:
        toresize = 1980
        v = 'h'
    else:
        toresize = 1080
        v = 'v'
    return [toresize, v]
```

and I'm calling it like this:

```
def generate_clip_var(clip_name, start_time):
    clip_audio = AudioFileClip(f"out/{clip_name}.mp3").set_start(start_time + 2)
    clip_video = ImageClip(f"out/{clip_name}.jpg").set_duration(1).set_start(start_time)

    if FitClip(clip_video.size)[1] == 'v':
        clip_video = ImageClip(f"out/{clip_name}.jpg").set_duration(clip_audio.duration + 1).set_position("center").set_audio(clip_audio).resize(height = FitClip(clip_video.size)[0]).set_start(start_time)
    else:
        clip_video = ImageClip(f"out/{clip_name}.jpg").set_duration(clip_audio.duration + 1).set_position("center").set_audio(clip_audio).resize(width = FitClip(clip_video.size)[0]).set_start(start_time)

    return [clip_audio, clip_video]
```

My problem is that whenever image is too small or too big it just goes outside bounds.

help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the `moviepy` native function `resize()`:

```
from moviepy.video.fx.resize import resize

def generate_clip_var(clip_name, start_time):
    clip_audio = AudioFileClip(f"out/{clip_name}.mp3").set_start(start_time + 2)
    clip_video = ImageClip(f"out/{clip_name}.jpg").set_duration(1).set_start(start_time)

    # Resize the clip_video object to fit within a 1980x1080 frame while maintaining its aspect ratio
    clip_video = resize(clip_video, width=1980, height=1080)

    # Set the duration and audio of the resized clip_video object
    clip_video = clip_video.set_duration(clip_audio.duration + 1).set_position("center").set_audio(clip_audio).set_start(start_time)

    return [clip_audio, clip_video]
```